# How to show sql table data in hierarchy in JAVA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I have 2 tables unit and unit_hier. unit table contains some static data and unit_hier table contains hierarchy relation.

```
**UNIT TABLE**
UNIT_ID     UNIT_NAME       DESC                                                  
1           Test1           Test 1                 
2           Test2           Test 2  
3           Test3           Test 3  
4           Test4           Test 4  
5           Test5           Test 5  
6           Test6           Test 6  
7           Test7           Test 7   
8           Test8           Test 8  
9           Test9           Test 9  
10          Test10          Test 10  
11          Test11          Test 11  
12          Test12          Test 12  
13          Test13          Test 13  
14          Test14          Test 14
```

```
**UNIT_Hier Table**
PARENT_UNIT_ID  CHILD_UNIT_ID  
1               2     
1               3    
1               4    
2               5    
2               6    
5               7      
5               8    
3               9     
7               10     
3               11     
3               12     
4               13     
5               14
```

Now as per unit_hier table I need to frame a response json.

Below are the expected response json:

```
{
        "UNIT_ID": 1,
        "UNIT_NAME": "Test1",
        "DESC": "Test 1",
        "childUnit":[
            {"UNIT_ID": 2,
            "UNIT_NAME": "Test2",
            "DESC": "Test 2",
            "childUnit":[ 
                {"UNIT_ID": 5,
                "UNIT_NAME": "Test5",
                "DESC": "Test 5",
                "childUnit":[ 
                    {"UNIT_ID": 7,
                    "UNIT_NAME": "Test7",
                    "DESC": "Test 7",
                    "childUnit":[ 
                        {"UNIT_ID": 10,
                        "UNIT_NAME": "Test10",
                        "DESC": "Test 10",
                        "childUnit":[]
                        }
                        ]},

                    {
                    "UNIT_ID": 8,
                    "UNIT_NAME": "Test8",
                    "DESC": "Test 8",
                    "childUnit":[]
                    },
                    {
                    "UNIT_ID": 14,
                    "UNIT_NAME": "Test14",
                    "DESC": "Test 14",
                    "childUnit":[]
                    }


                {
                "UNIT_ID": 6,
                "UNIT_NAME": "Test6",
                "DESC": "Test 6",
                "childUnit":[]
                }
                ],

        {
            "UNIT_ID": 3,
            "UNIT_NAME": "Test3",
            "DESC": "Test 3",
            "childUnit":[
                {"UNIT_ID": 9,
                "UNIT_NAME": "Test9",
                "DESC": "Test 9",
                "childUnit":[]
                },
                {
                "UNIT_ID": 11,
                "UNIT_NAME": "Test11",
                "DESC": "Test 11"
                "childUnit":[]
                },
                {
                "UNIT_ID": 12,
                "UNIT_NAME": "Test12",
                "DESC": "Test 12",
                "childUnit":[]
                }
        ],
        {
        "UNIT_ID": 4,
        "UNIT_NAME": "Test4",
        "DESC": "Test 4",
        "childUnit":[
        {"UNIT_ID": 13,
        "UNIT_NAME": "Test13",
        "DESC": "Test 13",
        "childUnit":[]
        }
        ]
        }
        }
    }
```

Problem is I tried simply parsing the data. I am getting only 1 level of parsing but I need to get all the child till the last element where no child exists.

Comment: As far as  know SQL does not support hierarchical queries, so neither does (standard) JPA. Databases may have proprietary extensions, like the `START WITH...CONNECT BY` in Oracle, but you will still have to execute it as a native query and do some processing of the results. The alternative is executing queries recursively, which is slow, but may be acceptable if your dataset is small enough and is not being queries frequently.

Comment: where are your classes? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

JPA does support recursive parent/child relationships via normal 
bidirectional @ManyToOne/@OneToMany
Your table structure needs changing before you can use it though. You don't need a separate hierarchy table. Just add a parentId column to the main table and map via it bidirectionally.